# What's with pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having some trouble understanding the use of pointers in this program:

```
#include<iostream.h>
class ABC
{
    public:
        int data;
        void getdata()
        {
            cout<<"Enter data: ";
            cin>>data;
            cout<<"The number entered is: "<<data;
        }
};
void main()
{
    ABC obj;
    int *p;
    obj.data = 4;
    p = &obj.data;
    cout<<*p;
    ABC *q;
    q = &obj.data;
    q->getdata();
}
```

I get everything until the following step : `ABC *q;`
What does that do? My book says it's a class-type pointer (it's very vague with pathetic grammar). But what does that mean? A pointer pointing to the address of the class ABC?

If it is, then the next step confuses me. `q = &obj.data;`
So we're pointing this pointer to the location of *data*, which is a variable. How does that `ABC *q;` fit in, then?

And the last step. What does `q->getdata();` do? My book says it's a '*pointer to member function operator*', but gives no explanation.

Glad to recieve any help!

Comment: Throw away that book.

Comment: I'm assuming that `q = &obj.data` equals `q = &obj` ?

Comment: First, the q is a pointer to an ABC class object, so `q=&obj`. Secondly `q->getdata()` will invoke the method for that instance of ABC

Comment: I'm curious - what's the title of that book? Or did you already throw it away? :D

Comment: It looks like the author is either making mistakes or making needless and hideous assumptions - ie: that a pointer to the first data member in a class is the same as a pointer to the object.  Follow the copious advice already given, get a new book.

Comment: @unwind I really think I'm gonna do exactly that. I had such an excellent book while learning Java. *This* book was presribed by my board (along with a few others). I'm definitely gonna get another one.

Comment: @thokra A trashy book by some guy called 'R. D. Supekar': *Computer Science for XIIth Bifocal Computer Science*.

Comment: I just realised, even the title is so horrid. And iterative.

Comment: @user1158692 - just to be completely clear, that assignment is illegal: you can't assign the address of an `int` into a pointer to `ABC`. So not only would the author be making a bad assumption, he'd be using a bad compiler.

Comment: @PeteBecker It certainly doesn't build for me.  People often lose the odd cast when transcribing from a book though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ABC * q
```

This instruction creates to pointer to fragment of memory, where resides instance of class ABC. For example:

```
q = new ABC();
```

This instantiates ABC and stores address of that instance in q variable.

```
ABC abc;
q = &abc;
```

This instantiates ABC *automatically* (that means, compiler takes care of allocation and deallocation of that instance) and stores address to that class in q.

Also, `->` is not *pointer to member function operator*. This is only shorter way of writing something else:

```
a -> b
```

equals

```
(*a).b
```

If you know, that `a` points to a class instance (or struct instance, what in C++ is *more less* the same) and you want to access a member (field or method) of that instance, you can quickly write `a->b = 5;` or `a->DoSth();` instead of `(*a).b = 5;` or `(*a).DoSth();`.

Comment: I think OP was confused by `q = &obj.data`.

Comment: Fun fact `->` isn't the only C++ operator with a simple definition like that. The array subscript operator `a[b]` is defined as `*((a) + (b))` meaning that `b[a]` is just as valid.

Comment: "This instruction creates to pointer to fragment of memory, where resides instance of class ABC"  I think this is wrong.  ABC *p; only declares a pointer if you don't assign anything to the pointer than it has no meaning; think of what a compiler would generate for the declaration (assuming it does not strip away not used symbols)

Comment: That's quite fluent. It will still be a pointer to instance of `ABC` even though there is no actual instance. In C++ you can, for example, allocate a bunch of memory, cast it to `ABC*` and sometimes it will even work (if `ABC` is not polymorphic and if you allocated enough memory), but of course this is something you **definitely** don't want to do. The point is, that compiler always believes, that there is `ABC` in the place pointed to by p.

Comment: @Pandrei I'm sorry, I didn't understand that at all! :P

Comment: @Mgetz What exactly do the brackets signify in `*((a) + (b))`?

Comment: I think [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) explains it best in section 5.2.1 Subscripting

Answer (score 5):

That book is wrong because it should be:

```
ABC *q;
q = &obj;
q->getdata();
```

Or using a int pointer:

```
ABC *q;
int *qq;
qq = &obj.data;
q = &obj;
q->getdata();
```

Comment: actually because int data is the first member of the class &obj and &obj.data represent the same address. So it'd perfectly valid

Comment: No, It's not perfectly valid.  The compiler will complain that it can't convert int* to ABC*.  Yes, they will be the same address, but they aren't the same type, and therefore the original code won't compile.

Comment: @Pandrei Yeah, it's not only about the memory location. The data-types matter too.

Answer (score 2):

The `q = &obj.data` part, as stated by 'Lame-up-duck' doesn't add up:

Your pointer:

```
ABC *q;
```

Is a variable, usually 32 or 64 bit. It can contain the memory address of an object, in this case of type `ABC`

So you have this object in `obj`.

To let the pointer actual 'point' to this object, you'll need to assign the memory address value to the pointer with the 'address operator' `&`, like this:

```
q = &obj;
```

`q` now points to the `obj` object. You can access this `obj` object with

```
q->
```

Now `q->getdata()` will call the `getdata` function in `obj`.

Comment: "`q` now points to the `obj.data` object."  Are you sure about that?  :-)

Comment: @user1158692: thanks :), I was confused due to the 'bad book'

Answer (score 2):

```
ABC obj;
ABC *q;
q = &obj.data;
```

should not compile.

More logical would be

```
q = &obj;
```

which assigns the address of `obj` (an instance of class `ABC`) to the pointer-to-ABC called `q`.

Once this is done, if you wanted to call getdata on q you use

```
q -> getdata();
```

...because q is a pointer.  Compare this to what you'd do with `obj` (which is a stack variable)

```
obj.getdata();
```

Same function, called in different ways.

Comment: actually it compiles and it's perfectly fine. the problem would be in case of the following statement: q=&(obj.data) because now you are assigning a int*  to a ABC* and the compiler can't do an implicit cast.

Comment: @Pandrei No, it doesn't compile. I tried it. The compiler highlighted the following line: `q=&obj.data;` and gave me the following error: "Cannot convert 'int*' to 'ABC*'".

Comment: Putting the brackets won't make any difference. The compiler will accept `obj.data` as one element even without brackets. It won't point `q` to simply `obj` just because you haven't included the whole thing in brackets.